# Rails Devise Registrations sign_up not rendering with custom layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, layout, devise

My sign_up page stopped rendering using my custom layout, other device views work properly and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here are the pertinent details:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'devise'
```

initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "form"
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout "form"
  Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "form"
  Devise::UnlocksController.layout "form"            
  Devise::PasswordsController.layout "form"        
end
```

registrations_controller.rb:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  layout "layouts/account", only: [:edit]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end
  ...
```

form.html.haml exists in the views/layouts folder

output from server:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (6.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve this issue was to add the following line under the other layout call in the RegistrationsController...

```
layout "layouts/form", only: [:new]
```

I don't know why for sure, but I suspect the first layout call even though it should have only applied to :edit somehow overrode the initializer setting the layout.